# how to access API routes with middleware auth:api in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am able to access routes declared in the api.php(route) with middleware **'api'**. But not able to do the same with the routes that has **'auth:api'**.
I guess only authenticated users can access the latter route. But when i access it after logging in , it just redirects me to home. how to fix this or am i following wrong procedure ?

```
Route::get('/user', function () {
echo "Hello";
})->middleware('auth:api');

Route::get('/work',function(){
echo "Hello";
})->middleware('api');
```

Comment: When you are using auth:api you have to pass access_token as parameter string and access_token field should be exist in Database Table. @NaveenKumar

Comment: Maybe the documentation can help a bit https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport

Answer (score 0):

Check Laravel passport, it provides a nice way to implement OAuth2 and once you install passport create password client and make a post request to Oauth/token and get personal access_token.

Once you have the access_token you can make request to middleware auth:api